# Change order status after checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change the status of my order based on current order status. If my current order status is pending I want to change it to completed after paying in pay for order (checkout/order-pay). However, after paying the status is still processing instead of completed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_change_status_function', 10, 1 );
function my_change_status_function( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if( $order->get_status() == 'pending' ){
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }else{
       $order->update_status( 'processing' );
    }
}
```

Comment: for which all payment methods do you want this to happen? it's good to extend the WC class so any incorrect email isn't triggered, if you use woocommerce_thankyou, then the users will receive multiple emails of status change.

Comment: @Akshat, i want this to happen if the payment method is cod, i just want to change user's order status to completed upon pay for order if the current status is pending payment.

Comment: so in short you want to set all the cod orders as "completed" or only if it has downloadable items? because if you set condition based on order status then your customers will receive multiple emails of status update.